# i want to use the function in different class for single record id the function is currently used for bulk records, the function execute!

Tags: apex, batch

```java
global class iCRM_PopulateDeliveryDateOnOutletBatch 
                implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful, PSR_TerritoryManagementBatchJob{
                    
    PSR_TerritoryManagemenBatchJob_Scheduler scheduler;
    global BatchApexJobMeta__c jobMeta;
    String marketCode;
    global Integer noOfRecords = 0;
                                    
    global virtual void initialize(PSR_TerritoryManagemenBatchJob_Scheduler s, BatchApexJobMeta__c scheduledJobMeta) {
        scheduler = s;
        jobMeta = scheduledJobMeta;
    }
                    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        scheduler.hasErrored = false;
        String mockQuery = 'select id,Affiliation__r.From_Account__c from Supplier_Delivery_Date__c LIMIT 1';
                        
        if (jobMeta == null) {  
            // If jobMeta was not retrieved, then this query is launched instead, 
            // so process can continue without exceptions
            return Database.getQueryLocator(mockQuery);
        }
                        
        scheduler.upsertBatchJob(jobMeta, bc.getJobId());
                        
        Database.QueryLocator oQueryLocator;
        marketCode = jobMeta.Country_Code__c;
        try {
            oQueryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator(createQuery(marketCode));
                            
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug(e);
            // If an exception is thrown, then this query is launched instead, 
            // so process can continue without exceptions
            oQueryLocator = Database.getQueryLocator(mockQuery);
                            
            // Log error
            if (scheduler != null) {
                String errorMessage = e.getMessage() + '. Line: ' + e.getLineNumber();
                scheduler.logBatchJobError(jobMeta, 'Failed', errorMessage, 'Start', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords);
            }
        }
                        
        return oQueryLocator;
    }
                    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
        // Increment total number of records by batch size
        noOfRecords += Integer.valueOf(scope.size());
                        
        // If no records were retrieved, it stops process 
        if (scope.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
                        
        // Set Batch flag to prevent trigger being executed because of Batch related DML operations
        PSR_TriggerHelper.setBatchExecution();
                            
        try {
            List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
            List<Supplier_Delivery_Date__c> sdds = (List<Supplier_Delivery_Date__c>) scope;
            List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
            List<String> affiliationIds = new List<String>();
            for(Supplier_Delivery_Date__c sdd: sdds){
                accountIds.add(sdd.Affiliation__r.From_Account__c);
                affiliationIds.add(sdd.Affiliation__c);
            }
            system.debug(affiliationIds);
            system.debug(accountIds);
            List<AggregateResult> ars = [select Affiliation__c af,Min(Delivery_Date__c) from Supplier_Delivery_Date__c where Affiliation__c in :affiliationIds and Delivery_Date__c > TODAY group by Affiliation__c];
            Map<String,Date> affiliationAndDateMap = new Map<String,Date>();
            for(AggregateResult ar:ars){
                affiliationAndDateMap.put(String.valueOf(ar.get('af')),Date.valueOf(ar.get('expr0')));
            }
            Map<Id,Affiliation__c> affiliatioMap = new Map<Id,Affiliation__c>([select id, from_Account__c from Affiliation__c where id in :affiliationIds]);
            Map<String,String> accountAndAffiliationIdMap = new Map<String,String>();
            for(Id affiliationId: affiliatioMap.keyset()){
                accountAndAffiliationIdMap.put(affiliatioMap.get(affiliationId).from_Account__c, affiliationId);
            }
            Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([select id,Order_Delivery_Date__c from account where id in :accountIds]);
            for(String accountId: accountIds){
                Account acct =  accountMap.get(accountId);
                String affiliationId = accountAndAffiliationIdMap.get(accountId);
                acct.Order_Delivery_Date__c = affiliationAndDateMap.get(affiliationId);
                accounts.add(acct);
            }
            if(accounts.size() > 0){
                Database.SaveResult[] srList =Database.update(accounts,false);
                                
                //To record the error of the failed records.
                Map <Id, String> failedRecords = PKF_Utility.getFailedRecords(scope,srList); 
                scheduler.logFailedRecords(jobMeta, 'Running', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords, failedRecords);   
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            String errorMessage = e.getMessage() + '. Line: ' + e.getLineNumber();
            scheduler.logBatchJobError(jobMeta, 'Running', errorMessage, 'Execute', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords);
        }
    }
                    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        if (jobMeta != null ) {
            if(!scheduler.hasErrored){
                scheduler.updateBatchJob(jobMeta, 'Successful', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords);
            } else {
                scheduler.logBatchJobError(jobMeta, 'Failed', 'Completed', 'Execute', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords);
            }
                
            try {
                scheduler.scheduleNextJob('Miscellaneous');
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                String errorMessage = e.getMessage() + '. Line: ' + e.getLineNumber();
                scheduler.logBatchJobError(jobMeta, 'Failed', errorMessage, 'Finish', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords);
            }
        }
    }
                    
    private String createQuery(String marketCode){
        String query;
        if(!string.isBlank(marketCode)){
            query = 'select id,Affiliation__c,Affiliation__r.From_Account__c from Supplier_Delivery_Date__c where Delivery_Date__c = TODAY and Affiliation__r.Market_Code__c = :marketCode';         
        }
        else{
            query = 'select count(id),Affiliation__r.From_Account__r.Market_Code__c mr from Supplier_Delivery_Date__c where Delivery_Date__c = TODAY group by Affiliation__r.From_Account__r.Market_Code__c ';
        }
        return query;
    }
    /*
        This method runs the aggregate query to find the number of records which will be processed by the batch.
        It will be called from batch 'iCRM_SchedulePendingBatchJobs'.We are returning null in this case because we want this batch 
        to run everytime.
    */
    public Map<String,Integer> getNumberOfRecord(){
        Map<String,Integer> mrktRecords = new Map<String,Integer>();
        String marketCode;
        Integer noOfRecords;
                
        for(AggregateResult ar : Database.query(createQuery(null))){
            marketCode = String.valueOf(ar.get('mr'));
            noOfRecords = Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'));
            mrktRecords.put(marketCode,noOfRecords);
        }
                        
        return mrktRecords;
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can move the logic to its own method:

```
public static void updateOrderDeliveryDates(List<sObject> scope) {
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        List<Supplier_Delivery_Date__c> sdds = (List<Supplier_Delivery_Date__c>) scope;
        List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
        List<String> affiliationIds = new List<String>();
        for(Supplier_Delivery_Date__c sdd: sdds){
            accountIds.add(sdd.Affiliation__r.From_Account__c);
            affiliationIds.add(sdd.Affiliation__c);
        }
        system.debug(affiliationIds);
        system.debug(accountIds);
        List<AggregateResult> ars = [select Affiliation__c af,Min(Delivery_Date__c) from Supplier_Delivery_Date__c where Affiliation__c in :affiliationIds and Delivery_Date__c > TODAY group by Affiliation__c];
        Map<String,Date> affiliationAndDateMap = new Map<String,Date>();
        for(AggregateResult ar:ars){
            affiliationAndDateMap.put(String.valueOf(ar.get('af')),Date.valueOf(ar.get('expr0')));
        }
        Map<Id,Affiliation__c> affiliatioMap = new Map<Id,Affiliation__c>([select id, from_Account__c from Affiliation__c where id in :affiliationIds]);
        Map<String,String> accountAndAffiliationIdMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(Id affiliationId: affiliatioMap.keyset()){
            accountAndAffiliationIdMap.put(affiliatioMap.get(affiliationId).from_Account__c, affiliationId);
        }
        Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([select id,Order_Delivery_Date__c from account where id in :accountIds]);
        for(String accountId: accountIds){
            Account acct =  accountMap.get(accountId);
            String affiliationId = accountAndAffiliationIdMap.get(accountId);
            acct.Order_Delivery_Date__c = affiliationAndDateMap.get(affiliationId);
            accounts.add(acct);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] srList =Database.update(accounts,false);
        //To record the error of the failed records.
        Map <Id, String> failedRecords = PKF_Utility.getFailedRecords(scope,srList); 
        scheduler.logFailedRecords(jobMeta, 'Running', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords, failedRecords);   
        }
}
```

---

Which is then called as normal from the execute method:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
    // Increment total number of records by batch size
    noOfRecords += Integer.valueOf(scope.size());
                    
    // Set Batch flag to prevent trigger being executed because of Batch related DML operations
    PSR_TriggerHelper.setBatchExecution();                            
    try {
        updateDeliveryDates(scope);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        String errorMessage = e.getMessage() + '. Line: ' + e.getLineNumber();
        scheduler.logBatchJobError(jobMeta, 'Running', errorMessage, 'Execute', bc.getJobId(), noOfRecords);
    }
}
```

You can then call `iCRM_PopulateDeliveryDateOnOutletBatch.updateOrderDeliveryDates` directly from your trigger as well.

Some additional work will be necessary, this was mostly a copy-paste job to illustrate the point.

---

Of course, this is a simple implementation change. I'd recommend that you go through this [Apex Enterprise Patterns: Service Layer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_patterns_sl) trailhead for more information on best practices.

---

Some additional notes:

```
    if (scope.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
```

I can guarantee you that this will never be true in actual batch execution. There is no reason to have this line of code here.

Similarly:

```
        if(accounts.size() > 0){
```

Is useless, as it doesn't really save much CPU time, and has no effect on governor limits. Performing DML on an empty list is treated as a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) (No Operation).